# Set column type for some columns, but not for all readr::read_csv()

Tags: r, parsing, import

I am reading in a fairy large data file, with about 300 variables. I am using readr:read_csv(), which, for 95% does the job. However, for 8 variables I get a parsing error. These variables are thought to be logicals, but they are in fact character. Now, I don't want to manually format all column types, since 95% is going correct. I only want to set the column type for those columns who get a parsing error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the data types of specific columns using the argument `col_types`, for example:

```
df <- read_csv(
  "my_file.csv", 
  col_types = cols(
    x = col_character(), # or string abbreviation "c"
    y = col_logical()
  )
)
```

with `x` and `y` being the column names. Not that all other columns will be parsed automatically, so you don't need to specify all columns. See the `readr` [documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/articles/readr.html) (section *Available column specifications*) for more details!

Answer (score 0):

can you try using the library(data.table) and the fread function.
for example `data=fread("fantastic_cluster.csv")`. With the `colClasses = c("date" = "character")` you can specify also the structure of some columns. If you a post a subset of your data I might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the type for those remaining type manually. For example, if all remaining columns that caused a parsing error should be logicals, you could use

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(across(c("COLUMNS_TO_CHANGE"), as.logical))
```

There are several ways to select multiple columns inside the `across`-funtion, for example `starts_With`, `ends_With`, `matches`, depending on how the columns are named and if there is a pattern for those columns to select.

Take a look into the `tidyverse`-package, especially `dplyr` and `tidyr` for tasks like that. The book [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is a good start.